# IE bug, autocomplete box position in iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, textbox, autocompletebox

After a few hours' of google search, i found that there is autocomplete box bug since almost 10 years ago, until now, on IE9 the bug is still there.

---

problem:

when i have an input:text inside iframe, there are positioning bug of the autocomplete box - tested on IE8-compatibility mode, IE8, IE9.

---

The problem maybe related to the iframe's parent class (note: may not be the style, because i tested on IE9 console, disabling the class style will not solve the problem; on the other hand, giving the same style but removing the class **PARTIALLY SOLVE** the autocomplete box positioning bug, and unfortunately only on IE9).

on IE8 and IE8 compatibility-mode, tried the same method, the position of the autocomplete box bug is still present: sometimes it is located around 50px below the input:text, sometimes it is about 8px above the input:text bottom (like IE9).

---

solution i founded from google result, people suggest "position:relative; left:0; top:0;", tested, doesn't work.

---

similar problem from another person: http://forums.asp.net/t/1538225.aspx/1

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

use position:fixed with iframe non resizable and movable.
in my case it was a jquery dialog using an iframe.

still one issue remains,on scroll using mouse the autofill box remain in place.